# Question about Vcc

Tags: arduino

I am working with an Arduino Mega 2560 and have an sensor connected to it.
I have read instructions about how to write code to read the supply voltage, Vcc, immediately prior to executing analogRead, on a connected sensor, in order to get the reference voltage for the ADC.
I have done this and found, that at the point of read, Vcc was varying widely between successive reads (from 4.8V - 5.2V). Why is this? and surely this is not very useful to know because it might have changed on the next analogRead?

Comment: Do you have sufficient bypass capacitors on your Vcc and analog ref inputs?  There could be significant noise on these lines if you haven't included them.  Using high current pulsing devices (relays, motors) can also put extra noise on the lines, use larger bypass capacitors to quiet these down. Also keep noisy traces away from the analog ref and even the analog gnd lines.

Answer (score 2):

#### The Take away

1. If your sensor outputs a voltage that is scaled as a portion of the input voltage, and your ADC uses a different voltage as a reference, you need to measure the reference voltage of the sensor to accurately convert the reading.
2. Use an oscillscope to verify the stability of the voltage reference. If the effect is real then look at your power draw and power supply. If it is a measurement issue see #3
3. Make sure you are respecting settling times after changing ADC channels. Also, the ADC expects a low-impedance source, so check the datasheet for typical input impedance of your sensor and keep in in mind that if it is above 10K or so you may have issues and require more settling time and a longer conversion time. Try taking more samples in a row to see if the value settles. This is also an issue if you are using the "set ADCRef to Vcc and measure internal ref" strategy as the internal reference has a relatively large impedance.
4. You need to scale the measured value using the most recent known value of the sensors reference voltage. You can either do this immediately in the code that reads the sensor, or store both values for processing later

#### The Details

An ADC gives you a bit value representing the voltage as a multiple of Vref

[image]

Many sensors and sensing devices present a simple resistive interface to the designer, where the sensing element acts as a voltage divider of sorts and a reading is done by measuring the voltage drop across it. I'm assuming since you are doing an `analogRead` that you are maybe using a sensor like this.

A simple thermistor is a good example. Like the following schematic

[image]

However, on the Arduino the Vref for the ADC when you are taking a measurement is not the same Vref as for thermistor. So to accurately measure the resistance of Rt you need to measure Vref of the sensor to accurately compute the voltage drop. Hence the strategy you are asking about.

There are ways around this, for example, a Pressure Sensor is commonly implemented as a [Wheatstone Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheatstone_bridge)

The voltage difference between the two branches is measured by the ADC as a differential signal, hence we do not care what the Vref of the Sensor actually is for the most part

[image]

These sensors typically come with sensitivity specifications at different input voltages, but usually this is not too significant at fluctuations of a few mV.

#### Next Question

The `Vcc` Voltage fluctuations are concering, but you need to be sure that these are not measurement errors. Use an Oscilloscope to verify the stabilty of the regulator. If you do see real fluctuations on the scope then it may be that you are either drawing too much power on the pins  or the arduino supply is so noisy (or too low for the regulator)

For reference the maximum ratings are given in the table below,

[image]

If this is a measurement issue, I would attempt see if there is a settling time issue, one-shot measurements on multi channel ADC's (like the one on your AVR)can be problematic. Additionally, if you are measuring the internal reference using the Vcc as Vref for the ADC (a common strategy proposed for arduino voltmenters) then keep in mind that the impedance of the internal reference is quite large, and likely will need to more settling time so more samples, or lower sample rate (more S&H time)

The datasheet for your device states:

> **26.6.1** - The ADC is optimized for analog signals with an output impedance of
> approximately 10k or less. If such a source is used, the sampling
> time will be negligible. If a source with higher impedance is used,
> the sampling time will depend on how long time the source needs to
> charge the S/H capacitor, which can vary widely. The user is
> recommended to only use low impedant sources with slowly varying
> signals, since this minimizes the required charge transfer to the S/H
> capacitor.

Comment: For @crasic. On measuring Vcc with an oscilloscope using various power sources I did not observe the wild variation (4.8-5.2) that I appeared to have measured. There was some high frequency noise (+-20mV) for all power sources and for some power sources a lower frequency (50Hz) sinosoid (25mV amplitude).